# Is there a way to program a chatbot for pepper?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, pepper

i am currently in the posession of a pepper bot, and wanted to program a chatbot. Because i am new to the whole pepper thing, i was looking for tutorials but only found outdated once.

This one doesnt work anymore, because Pepper_Chat_CMS is disabled: https://softbankroboticstraining.github.io/pepper-chatbot-api/#authentication-amp-setup

This one doesnt work anymore, becuase dialogflow switched drom V1 to V2 and i dont have credentials to use for the development anymore:
https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-qisdk/lessons/integrating-chatbot-dialogflow

At this point i am despreate for any help in this subject.

Comment: I do not know about Pepper_Chat_CMS, but it does not seem to be an officially supported service. It looks like it was provided in the context of a training, and not for further use. The tutorial about dialog flow is probably outdated if the API changed, but you can adapt it to other services. Did you try, and what, exactly, prevented you from making it work?

Comment: Can you add little bit more about the chatbot which you're going to integrate? Is your chatbot based on REST API?

Answer (score 0):

In [this page of the lesson you shared](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-qisdk/lessons/integrating-chatbot-dialogflow/integrating-qisdk-application), they explain how to create a `Chatbot` object that is compatible with the Qi SDK. You can replace the content of the replies it provides by any other function providing chatbot replies.